# distance redefined -finding area of curve satisfying condition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, area

Suppose we define the distance between two points $P=(x_1,y_1)$  and  $Q=(x_2,y_2)$ as $d(P,Q)=\max\{|x_2-x_1|,|y_2-y_1|\}$.

If points A and B have coordinates $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ respectively, then the area of the curve on which P lies, with $d(P,A)^2+d(P,B)^2=4$, is ...

I noticed that point $A,B,(0,2), (0,-2)$ satisfy the conditions, but I could not figure out exactly the curve on which they may lie. Can anyone please help me out of this. Thanks.

Comment: I think there are a couple of typos: in the first line it should be $Q=(x_2,y_2)$ and the equation of the locus probably is $d(P,A)^2+d(P,B)^2=4$. Apart that, I'm not sure of the meaning of "the area of the curves on which $P$ lies".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT.

In the diagram below I sketched the curve, in red. I leave it to you to figure out why it is so and to compute the area inside it.

[image]